# What is the relationship between the logistic function and the logistic loss function?

Tags: machine-learning, logistic-regression

The standard logistic function is [[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function#Mathematical_properties)]:

$$
f(x) = \frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}
$$

But the logistic loss function is typically defined as [[2](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~yandongl/loss.html)]:

$$
l(w^{\top} \cdot x) = \ln(1 + e^{-y(w^{\top} \cdot x)})
$$

I don't see a clear relationship, but when I tried to take the derivative of the logistic loss function, I got:

$$
\frac{\partial l}{\partial z} \frac{\partial g}{\partial w} = (-\frac{e^{-yz}}{1+e^{-yz}})(x) = -\frac{xe^{-y(w^{\top} \cdot x)}}{1+e^{-y(w^{\top} \cdot x)}}
$$

Which is *really close* to the derivative of the logistic function:

$$
f^{\prime}(x) = \frac{-e^{-x}}{(1+e^{-x})^2}
$$

What's the relationship?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}l(w^Tx)&=\ln(1+\exp(-y(w^T.x))\\&=-\ln\left( \frac{1}{1+\exp(-y(w^T.x)} \right)\\&=-\ln(f(-y(w^T.x))\end{align}

Comment: Thanks. Just to confirm, is my derivative of the logistic loss function correct?

Comment: I think you miss a $y$ in your numerator.